# GrailsMock domain findByUuid static method GORM

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-domain-class

Unit Testing ... can't figure this out.. 
I'm using 2.1.1 and how do I get the mocked domain static method .findByUuid is there special syntax for the .findBy???

code in Controller has domain class called MessageBus ...:

```
        log.debug("uuidStatus? = "+ uuidStatus)
        def messageBus = MessageBus.findByUuid(uuidStatus)  
        log.debug("messageBus is valid? = "+ messageBus)
```

How do I mock the domainClass.findByUuid

I've tried this in the ControllerTests:

```
    mockControl.demand.static.findByUuid() { uuidStatus -> 
        MessageBus mb = new MessageBus()
        mb.uuid="dce9d1bf-f3c2-4876-af68-6c9d272cf374"
        println("uuid = " +mb.uuid)
        return mb
        }
```

error:

> Controller uuidStatus? = dce9d1bf-f3c2-4876-af68-6c9d272cf374
>   core.DatastoreUtils Cannot unbind session, there's no SessionHolder registered
>   | Failure:  testStatus(ControllerTests)
>   |  junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No call to 'findByUuid' expected at this point. Still 1 call(s) to 'getAsMap' expected.
>       at grails.test.MockClosureProxy.doBeforeCall(MockClosureProxy.java:66)
>       at grails.test.AbstractClosureProxy.call(AbstractClosureProxy.java:74)
>       at Controller.status(CommentsController.groovy:84)
>       at ControllerTests.testStatus(ControllerTests.groovy:225)

I got this working, but I don't know why.  So I built new package and simple Book & LibraryController want to test method status.  At first when I build the simple project I got the same error message.
**!!Then after buggering with it a bit, it started working, it seems like modifying the mockup demand.static.find() *** changing the name of this and changing it back again was fix.  Strange.  IDK, but I've got to move on, if somebody else sees this are maybe it's a strangeness with version 2.1.1.

```
package testbook
class Book {
String name
String uuid 
static constraints = {
    uuid(unique: true)
}
}
```

Library Controller:
     package testbook
     class LibraryController {
    def status(){
        String uuid = params?.uuid
        log.debug("uuid="+uuid)
        def myBook = Book.findByUuid(uuid)
        log.debug("myBook.toString()="+myBook.toString())
        if(myBook){
            // do something 
            log.debug("doing something!!!")
        }
        render myBook
    }

ControllerTests:

```
package testbook
import grails.test.GrailsMock
import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*

@TestFor(LibraryController)
@Mock([Book])
class LibraryControllerTests {
 void testStatus() {
    def mockcontrol = new GrailsMock(Book)

    mockcontrol.demand.static.findByUuid(){uuid ->
        Book bookFound = new Book()
        bookFound.id = 1  // IMPORTANT for default .toString()
        bookFound.name = "Alice in Wonderland"
        bookFound.uuid = uuid
        println("bookFound=" + bookFound)
        return  bookFound //this returns null object
        }

    params.uuid="12356"
    Map model = controller.status()
    println("model" + model )// this is null
}
```

}

So the original error is gone for some reason. But I'm still getting a null object returned.

The model is still returned as a null. 
            Map model = controller.status() // returns null for the model.

Any explanation of why the mocked up domain is rendered as "null"?

Comment: Can you share your full test class?

Comment: @TestFor(PublisherController)
@Mock([ContentRouteProcessorService,MessageBus,FormatOutput,MsgsService])
class PublisherControllerTests {

Comment: added printlns, and you can't instantiate a mockedup class. 

findByUuid( is being called but it was returning null values)
the messageBus objects are all null 
eip.PublisherController messageBus is valid? = com.streamlinx.eip.MessageBus : null
So the real question is how do I mock the constructor method of mocked domain object? 
or
How do I mock .demand for the  if (myDomain) ?

Comment: You can click in "edit" to append information to your question.